# AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() is null

Tags: android

I Integrated Facebook in my app and getting the proper token. If the token already exists then it assigns it, and if it's the first time then it will make a request for the token. However, the token is not being received.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(
                    AccessToken oldAccessToken,
                    AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
                // Set the access token using
                // currentAccessToken when it's loaded or set.
            }
        };
        // If the access token is available already assign it.
        accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
```

Comment: Please describe your problem on top of just pasting a block of code. [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed that `GraphRequest.newMeRequest` sometimes does not delete old session data, so will return a null response in onComplete. As an alternative, you could use `GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(accessToken, "/me"...)`, with very similar results.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're not setting the access token in this block, just like the comment tells you to. I could be wrong, but is that the issue you're having?

```
    accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(
                AccessToken oldAccessToken,
                AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
            // Set the access token using
            // currentAccessToken when it's loaded or set.
            accessToken = currentAccesstoken;

        }
    };
```